# Joomla form creation

Tags: php, mysql, forms, joomla

good day,

I am using Joomla 1.5 and wanted to make a real estate management system for a university project. I have the database created. I was able to make the back-end part where the admin inserts/edits/deletes the property listing. However, I need some help with the front end search part. I haven't been able to find any tutorial that helps me make it front end. I am aware of the existing extensions and software that do it for you but i wanted to make it from scratch. any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the Joomla Docs have what you're looking for at :
[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component - Part 1](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)
and
[Creating a Hello World Module for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5)

Comment: These two links tell you exactly what you want to know:  How to create the front-end component to display the info, and how to create a module to do something like search for something, then display that result with the front-end component.  You can look at the installed joomla search module to see how they incorporate the database/searching logic, and include it in your module.

Comment: Is there a reason that this answer suddenly became unacceptable? - It's still correct.

Comment: sorry mate i clicked on it by mistake. I deeply apologize.

Comment: np...did it get your f/e component building up to speed?

Comment: No. I cannot seem to be getting the module to work. Its really pain staking.

Answer (score 1):

So do you mean you don't want to program the front end yourself but would like to use a tool for that? If so, don't. I have seen some tools and they were all bad, with only a few standard options and nothing specific really. I don't think you will get around coding some html and php, especially since you have your own database in the backend.

There are lots of very helpful tutorials. My favorite ones are at the new boston, such as [this php tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11) and [this html tutorial for beginners](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=40).

Cheers

Comment: Well I want to program the whole component not use some third party extensions like chronoforms.

Comment: @Fazleh Can you please further specify what help you need exactly.

Comment: Okay i start again.... I want to make a real estate management system where the customer can search for property in the front end. i am trying to make a module that helps the customer do that. have a look at http://jomestate.comdev.eu/ I want to make a module similar to the module they have shown in the bottom right corner called "JE Search Module". I ont know where to start from. I have the backend working but dont know how to do the front end.

Comment: @Fazleh Programming the front end is easy, even without much experience. But if you say you do not have much experience regarding web development, especially the backend and the server side programming will be extremely important for performance and security reasons. I strongly recommended reading into php and mysql programming as well as how to secure php code etc. Alternatively I can program it for you. Just send me a message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far and your advise. I have made the back-end component, though not very complex. I am not putting a lot of emphasis on the security as its just a university project. i am not sure how i can send u my work to have a look what i am doing wrong.

Comment: you can upload the files on an upload platform and post the links here.

Comment: hi, here is the file: https://rapidshare.com/files/1962290655/Estate.rar I have to warn you its not very fancy lol. i have included the mysql table. thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot open .rar files. Could you just zip it or 7zip it please?

Comment: rapidshare.com/files/108867496/Estate.zip Thanks. I haven't made the xml files for either components yet. Just copy and paste the files the respective joomla 1.5 installation. I should work

Comment: Thanks! I will look at the files and let you know when I make progress.

Comment: Not yet, sorry - it might take some time!